# Nested IFELSE in adding a column to a data frame

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I am trying to add a column to a data frame conditioned on values in existing column.

```
Data Frame:- df

Country

India
Mexico
Germany
```

I am now adding the Continent Column based on the country value.

```
df$Continent <- ifelse(df$Country=="India","Asia","Europe")
```

Output:-

```
Country   Continent 
India       Asia
Mexico      Europe
Germany     Europe
```

This leads to Mexico being categorized as in Europe. How can I add more if statements or it would be helpful if someone can hint me an alternate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the nested `ifelse` method, but there is probably a better solution, especially if your data frame has countries from more than 3 continents.

```
df$Continent <- ifelse(df$Country=="India","Asia",ifelse(df$Country=="Mexico","North America","Europe"))
```